# TextView TextSize - User preference vs scale independent pixels

Tags: android, android-layout

When we define a size of the text on a **TextView** using the sp as measure but the android user preference for font size is set to large, which of the configuration has preference over each other?

Comment: "which of the configuration has preference over each other" -- `sp` takes into account the user's preferred font scale, applying it to your text (or whatever else you sized using `sp` units). With that in mind, what do you mean by "configuration" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "dp" instead of "sp", your text size won't change upon android users font size preference.
Android Studio may suggest for using "sp". But you may use "dp" on textSize anyway.